# Creating Azure Key Vault using .NET assembly (Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault)

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am writing a .Net console application to create Key Vault but not able to find class/method in Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault assembly that allows creating Vault and setting service principal to that vault.

Can someone please point me to the assembly/class that i can use to create vault.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you are looking for is the **KeyVaultManagementClient** in the Microsoft.Azure.***Management***.KeyVault namespace.  This is defined in the management KeyVault assembly you can get from NuGet.

[image]

The main parts of the code to do this are shown below.  However, be advised that I have abbreviated some things (properties, subscription credentials, etc.) that you will have to further define and initialize.  If you want to see a complete solution check out the samples in the .[NET Azure SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net), in particular, the [KeyVaultManagement.Tests](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/src/ResourceManagement/KeyVaultManagement) project.

```
        // The resource group to create the vault in.
        const string resourceGroupName = "Vaults-Resource-Group";

        // The name of the vault to create.
        const string vaultName = "web-app-01-vault";

        // Define access policies to keys and secrets (abbreviated just to illustrate...)
        var accessPolicy = new AccessPolicyEntry
        {
            ApplicationId = sp, 
            PermissionsToKeys = new string[] { "all" }, 
            PermissionsToSecrets = new string[] { "backup", "create", "delete" } //etc.  just to name a few
        };

        // Define vault properties (abbreviated just to illustrate...)
        VaultProperties vaultProps = new VaultProperties()
        {
            EnabledForTemplateDeployment = true,
            AccessPolicies = new List<AccessPolicyEntry>()
            {
                accessPolicy
            }
        };

        // Initialize 'create parameters' to create the vault in "West US"
        VaultCreateOrUpdateParameters vaultParams = new VaultCreateOrUpdateParameters(vaultProps, "westus");

        // Initialize an instance to the mgmt client
        // NOTE: Need to initialize creds derived from SubscriptionCloudCredentials
        KeyVaultManagementClient mgmtClient = new KeyVaultManagementClient(creds);

        // Create the vault
        mgmtClient.Vaults.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, vaultName, vaultParams);
```

Comment: Thanks @Rick. I am able to create/update Vault using [KeyVaultManagementClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/KeyVaultManagement/KeyVaultManagement.Tests/VaultOperationsTest.cs)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, there is no such functionality in the client SDK (or, at least, i was not able to find that as well even by going through the code placed on the Github repo of the SDK). 
There is the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt620025.aspx) for Create/Update key vault, so you may create that by using that. Or PowerShell - it is possible to execute [Powershell from C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/) and i tried to do that - it works, but should be tested.