# How to get VaultProperties.NetworkAcls property from Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I need to extract Firewalls and virtual networks properties of a azure key vault and it look like the property I'm after is VaultProperties.NetworkAcls

This is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.keyvault.models.vaultproperties.networkacls?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_KeyVault_Models_VaultProperties_NetworkAcls

However I do not understand how to extract this property.

I'm using VS 2017 c# .net core 2.1

I already have Azure SKR installed and I have Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent 1.19.0 installed

I cannot find Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault.Models.VaultProperties
However what I can find is this

[VaultProperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmiwO.png)

Thanks
Eranga

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get vault info for a given subscription using below. You need below nuget as well.
**Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault**

```
private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string authority, string resource)
    {
        var adCredential = new ClientCredential(ClientId,
            ClientSecret);
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        return (await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, adCredential)).AccessToken;
    }

var token = await GetAccessTokenAsync(
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>",
            "https://management.azure.com/")
var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(token);
        var keyVaultManagementClient =
            new KeyVaultManagementClient(tokenCredentials)
            {
                SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
            }
return keyVaultManagementClient.Vaults.Get(resourceGroupName, vaultName)
```

Comment: You could accept your reply as answer to close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The class you are looking for is the KeyVaultManagementClient in the Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault namespace. This is defined in the management KeyVault assembly you can get from NuGet.

You can follow this thread for client object initialization.

[Creating Azure Key Vault using .NET assembly (Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276458/creating-azure-key-vault-using-net-assembly-microsoft-azure-keyvault)

Basically the class you would be intersted in is :

[image]

After initialization , you will be able to access Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault.Models
in which you can access vault properties:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks MohitVerma-MSFT. I was missing this nuget. Still wasn't that easy to get it working due to lack of examples/docs

Comment: Glad to know it helped . Will check if we can provide some sample code for the same.

Comment: BTW you can refer https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net for all the sdk and sample in dot net related to azure .